# What is the best way to type ()?

Tags: typing

This might not be exactly a programming question but it is related to programmers so if anyone knows the answer it will be someone here.
I have started suffering from some kind of RSI because of the way I type parenthesis and I was wondering what the best way to type them is without straining my wrist.

I currently type ( ) or _ by pressing Shift(Right) with my fourth finger (right hand) and then swivelling my wrist and flattening out my palm so that i can simultanesouly press one of the mentioned symbols with my index(trigger) finger.

Correction method or good links will be appreciated.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I've been spending way too much time on Lambda the Ultimate et al. o.O I expected a discussion about type systems and unit (the empty tuple)...

Comment: The Communist Duck is right. This would have been better placed in programmers.stackexchange.com. Oh well, next time. In any case I got the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @delnan: I was going to answer with "first you press the `shift` key, and while holding that down, press the key with the `(` on it"...

Comment: @CanSpice, that's like saying the best way to maintain relationships with people is to talk to them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use my left ring finger (or the one between middle and little) to push left shift and then right middle finger for parantheses. It's much easier than trying to stretch from right shift to 9/0.

It doesn't matter; why not just use the left shift?

Comment: Definitely the most comfortable for me.

Comment: This is actually touch typing basics, I'd say. You always press the shift opposing the side where the key is you want to type, you should never press shift and another key with the same hand at the same time. So this is the perfect answer, I'd say.

Comment: Thanks for inadvertently reminding me I need to learn to touch type. I know I manage to get pretty decent speeds with 2 fingers+2 more for shift/backspace, but still. ;P

Comment: Right middle finger for parentheses? That's not what Mavis Beacon told me.

Answer (score 2):

In touch-typing courses I was always taught to use the opposite hand to use the shift key. Thus for your example, I'd use my left pinky to hit the left shift key, then hit the `(`, `)`, or `_` keys. It saves on strain.

Answer (score 1):

I press shift with my left pinky and then the ( key with my right middle finger and the ) with my right ring finger. This is how I learned to do it back in the day and it's stuck. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Never thought about it.. I still type with two fingers, I can just do it quickly!

I use my little/pinky finger on right shift and the one next to my thumb on the number key.  Its comfortable enough.

Get bigger hands or a smaller keyboard perhaps?   Or, use left shift so you don't have to strain :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use an ergo keyboard. The MS natural 4000 allows for the right handed shift-9/0 with a minimum of discomfort. It also includes specific peren keys above the number pad.